# AutoLayout does not work properly on ios 8.3

Tags: ios, objective-c, facebook, autolayout

I am trying to add the facebook button.

Since you cannot drag and drop facebook button from the interface builder, you need to do programatically.

I add a dummy button with no text and try to assign its constraints to facebook button. It works on the 10.1 simulator, but when I test on 8.3 simulator it does not. I wonder what i am doing wrong?

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];
    facebookLoginButton = [[FBSDKLoginButton alloc] init];
    [self.view addSubview:facebookLoginButton];
}

-(void)viewDidLayoutSubviews {
    [super viewDidLayoutSubviews];
    facebookLoginButton.frame = dummyButton.frame;
}
```

ios 8.3 shows the facebook login button at the origin of the screen

[image]

ios 10.1 shows the facebook login button exactly on the right button which matches dummy button position.

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Setting an object's `frame` directly isn't using auto layout.  Auto layout uses constraints, and adding a view programatically will result in implicit constraints being added unless you set `translatesAutoResizingMaskIntoConstraints` to `false`.

Auto layout will override the frame the next time it recomputes the layout.

However, you can easily add the button in Interface Builder directly;  `FBSDKLoginButton` inherits from `FBSDKButton` which inherits from `UIButton`.

You can simply add a UIButton in Interface Builder and then set its custom class to `FBSDKLoginButton`